# ListView ItemClick Not Responding

Tags: listview, xamarin.android

I have a ListView control inside my main activity layout.  On each item in my ListView I have a button for viewing details (opening a new activity) and viewing a map (opens external google map app).  The problem that I'm having is I'd like the user to be able to click on the ListView item itself (not a button) so that the map (inside the fragment which is above the ListView ) can be updated.  For some reason my ListView.itemclick event doesn't execute when I click on a ListView item.  Do I need to add something to my code to get this to work?  I've scoured the web and found several suggests for fixing this, but nothing works.

Main Activity Layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:rowCount="3"
android:columnCount="1">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#FFDAFF7F" android:focusable="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity Code:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        try
        {
            // instantiate markList 
            this.markerList = new List<Marker>(); 

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // set toolbar
            var toolbar = this.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            this.SetActionBar(toolbar);
            this.ActionBar.Title = "Customer Map";

            // setup map
            this.SetUpMap();

            // get the current location
            this.locationManager = (LocationManager)this.GetSystemService(LocationService);
            var criteria = new Criteria { Accuracy = Accuracy.Coarse, PowerRequirement = Power.Medium };
            this.provider = this.locationManager.GetBestProvider(criteria, true);
            this.currentLocation = this.locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(this.provider);
            this.geoCoder = new Geocoder(this);

            // set up background color
            this.SetBackgroundColorOfLinearLayout();

            // setup the list view
            this.listView = this.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List);
            this.listView.NestedScrollingEnabled = true;                                                                           

            var customer = new CustomerService();
            this.tableItems = customer.GetCustomerInfo("104", this.currentLocation.Latitude.ToString(), this.currentLocation.Longitude.ToString());

            this.listView.ItemClick += this.ListView_ItemClick;

            this.listView.Adapter = new ListOfLocationAdapter(this, this.tableItems);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var errorMessage = "An error occurred during processing the main activity";
            if (ex.InnerException != null && ex.InnerException.ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.InnerException.ToString();
            }

            var errorOccurred = new Intent(this, typeof(ErrorOccurred));
            errorOccurred.PutExtra("ErrorMessage", errorMessage);
            this.StartActivity(errorOccurred);                
        }
    }



    private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = this.tableItems.ElementAt(e.Position);
        var item1 = item.FullName;
        Toast.MakeText(this, "delegate", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
```

List of Locations Layout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="70dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff">
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:columnCount="2">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CustomerName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CustomerNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:text="Details"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonDetails"
            android:textSize="9dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        <Button
            android:text="Directions"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonOpenMap"
            android:textSize="9dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

ListOfLocations Adapter

```
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {            

        this.view = convertView ?? this.context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListOfLocations, null);

        // fill values into textview
        var item = this.items[position];
        this.view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.CustomerName).Text = item.FullName;
        this.view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Address).Text = this.ReturnFullAddress(item);
        this.view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Distance).Text = this.FormatDistance(item.ApproxDistance);
        this.view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.CustomerNumber).Text = item.CustomerNumber;

        // add click event to open map button
        this.view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonOpenMap).Click += delegate
        {
            var geoURL = "geo:0,0?q=" + this.ReturnFullAddress(item) + "&z=20";
            var geoUri = Uri.Parse(geoURL);
            var mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, geoUri);                
            this.context.StartActivity(mapIntent);
        };

        // add click event to details button
        this.view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonDetails).Click += delegate
        {
            var activity = new Intent(this.context, typeof(CustomerDetail));
            activity.PutExtra("CustomerNumber", item.CustomerNumber);
            this.context.StartActivity(activity);
        };

        return this.view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer to this question on this site:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/871/how-do-i-get-itemclick-of-a-listview-to-get-called-not-sure-what-have-wrong

You have to add these property values to the buttons on the listview items.

```
 var imageButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imageButton1);
 imageButton.Focusable = false;
 imageButton.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
 imageButton.Clickable = true;
```